# How to use Firebase's ".info/connected" location in a correct manner to check for internet access?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Realtime Database in my Android app and have tried using **Firebase's** `.info/connected` location to check for internet access, but I am unable to use it in a reliable way to check for the state of the connection.

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities),

> Firebase Realtime Database provides a special location at `/.info/connected` which is updated every time the Firebase Realtime Database client's connection state changes.

For example, I have a `RecyclerView` in my main app screen that depends upon data fetched from the **RTDB**, like so

```
// Fragment

sellerRV = binding.sellerInfoRecyclerView
val adapter = SellerRecyclerViewAdapter()

sellerViewModel.initLoadingBalanceData()

// I am not doing anything after knowing about the connection state, just checking where I should call it
sellerViewModel.checkFBConnectivity()

sellerViewModel.repoBalanceDataListener.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    adapter.submitList(sellerBalanceList)
    sellerRV.adapter = adapter
})
```

After checking for connection state in the shown position (perhaps naively) and running the app, the `Log` look like this

```
2020-06-22 00:28:30.843 10092-10092/com.example.paylater D/firebaseRepo: not connected
2020-06-22 00:28:33.032 10092-10092/com.example.paylater D/firebaseRepo: connected
```

even though the list is visible, and the output is correct.

**So, my question is, how (or where) should I check for the state of the connection to have a consistent and reliable way to know if the user is connected or not, and then decide to initiate fetching the data ?**

Comment: What is the problem you're running into?  The docs are clear how to query that special location.  You'll have to find a way to work that into your app in a way that matches your app's architecture and UI requirements.  That's a pretty broad set of decisions to make.

Comment: The log output looks normal to me. as it takes a few seconds for the client to connect to the Firebase servers, it first fires an `.info/connected` event with `false` and then later with `true` once the connection is established. What's the problem you're having with this behavior?

Comment: @FrankVanPuffelen the problem that I am facing is that I need to query the location to know if I should inform the end-user to connect to a network or not, if they have not already done it, but since it fires off `false` at the start, I am unable to check it at startup to know the state. But seeing your comment, I realise that it is natural for it to first give a `false` and then `true`. So regarding that, what would be your suggestion on working in a delay of some kind before checking and then querying the location to see if it is connected and then telling the user, if they are offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it takes a few seconds for the client to connect to the Firebase servers, it first fires an `.info/connected` event with `false` and then later with `true` once the connection is established.

The usual way apps visualize this to the user is by showing a "connecting..." message or animation on startup, and then waiting for a bit. If the connect is established (so the listener becomes `true`), they remove the message. If a certain time interval passed, they show a "this is taking longer than expected, check your internet connection" type message.

Comment: Huge thanks for answering the question, which in hindsight seems like such a silly thing to ask. Also, and I hope this isn’t extraneous to the matter, since I am exclusively connecting to the Firebase servers is it necessary for me to perform a network check for the device too or can I only check for a connection with the server through this method?

Comment: It really all depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If you want to show the user whether they are connected to the database, listening to `.info/connected` should be all that's needed. But if you want to inform them whether they have a network connection, you should (also) check *that*.

Comment: Oh, okay I see what you mean. So if I need to specifically inform my users that even though they are connected to a network, they need to be connected to the Firebase servers too, then I go for the latter along with the Firebase `.info/connected` query and if my intention is to only inform them that they aren't connected to the Firebase servers then I only go for the `.info/connected` query. Finally and again, big thanks for taking the time to answer all of my questions.